# Set ComboBox SelectedItem in DataTemplate to itself

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So I have a small problem with `SelectedItem` in a ComboBox.

First of all, I have a template that I use for the items inside the ComboBox. Its because I want to display an Icon and a text for every Item.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonsComboBox" DataType="asi:Person">
    <WrapPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="40" Height="30" Source="{Binding Path=Symbol, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
            <vw:Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, this template is from the DataType `Person`.

Now, I use this ComboBox inside another DataTemplate. The DataTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonsTemplate" DataType="asi:Person">
    <vw:ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonsComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPersons}" SelectedItem="???">
</DataTemplate>
```

The property `AllPersons` is a list of all the persons that work in a company. A person has two properties `Name`and `Symbol` (image of their face).

```
AllPersons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Jenny", Symbol = new Image.FromFile("Path") },
    new Person { Name = "Mike", Symbol = new Image.FromFile("Path") }
    new Person { Name = "Peter", Symbol = new Image.FromFile("Path") }
    new Person { Name = "Nicole", Symbol = new Image.FromFile("Path") }
}
```

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Image Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

At the end I want to display alot of ComboBoxes (using an ItemsControl). Each ComboBox represents a person. But I want to be able to switch persons. The SelectedItem should be the item in SelectedDepartment.Persons

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDepartment.Persons, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PersonTemplateSelector}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

So basically what I want is to set the SelectedItem of my ComboBox to be itself so SelectedItem="{Binding}". But the ItemSource is a different one. They just have the same DataType

Comment: Does the Action class have an Actions property? Please post your class definition(s).

Comment: Itself = `DataContext`? Does `SelectedItem="{Binding}"` works or not (more likely `OneWay`/`OneTime` binding)? My guess you simply need to override `Equals()` in `Action`.

Comment: @mm8 I have updated my question to make it alot easier to understand what I mean

Comment: A Person has no AllPersons property so how is your PersonsTemplate supposed to work? And where do you want to store the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you redesign your data to support person selection in a separate viewmodel.

```
class MultiplePeopleContainer
{
    public ICollection<Person> AllPersons { get; } // list of all selectable person objects

    public ICollection<PersonContainer> DisplayedPersons { get; } // list of displayed persons where the actual person can be selected from combobox
}

class PersonContainer
{
    public Person SelectedPerson { get; set; } // person whos properties should be displayed
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Image Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Then the XAML becomes a lot easier

```
<!-- same as in question-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonsComboBox" DataType="asi:Person">
    <WrapPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="40" Height="30" Source="{Binding Path=Symbol, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
            <vw:Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- new -->
<DataTemplate DataType="asi:MultiplePeopleContainer">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SelectablePersons" Source="{Binding AllPersons}"/>

            <DataTemplate DataType="asi:PersonContainer">
                <vw:ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonsComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectablePersons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedPersons}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Side note: The `<WrapPanel>` in `PersonsComboBox` template is not really useful